# Smarty query count inside another query

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

I'm trying to show how many "replies" each comment has.

The query:

```
$sql = "SELECT c.*, a.username, a.avatar FROM user_wall c LEFT JOIN account a ON c.fid=a.id WHERE c.tid='". (int) $user[id]."' AND c.parent IS NULL ORDER BY `cid` DESC LIMIT 0, 10";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    $comments = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $cid = $row[cid];
        $comments[] = $row;
        $smarty->assign('comments', $comments);

        // Get how many replies the comment has
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) AS `total` FROM `user_wall` WHERE parent='".$cid."'");
        $tmp = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
        $smarty->assign('rcount', $tmp['total']);
    }   
}
```

What I have on the smarty template:

```
{foreach item="comments" from="$comments"}
    <div class="bubble2">
        <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="cinfo">By <a href="#">{$comments.username}</a>, {$comments.time}</div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            {$comments.comment}
        <div class="c-actions">
            <a href="#"><i class="icon-comments"></i> ({$rcount}) Replies</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
{/foreach}
```

The user_wall table:
[image]

The result:

[image]

The problem is that every comment now says that it has "3" replies, when the only one that does is the 2nd comment (Hello, this is a test! :-)). How can I fix this? Is there a better approach to my idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what if you do something as if($tmp['total'] > 0 ) { $smarty->assign('rcount', $tmp['total']);} else { $smarty->assign('rcount', 0);}

Comment: Didn't work, still shows 3 on every post.

Comment: I think u need to wrap the count in the comment array for smarty to loop through and display. Check the answer from Nostalgie

Comment: It seems that's what I was doing wrong. Thanks for your interest in my question, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = "SELECT c.*, a.username, a.avatar FROM user_wall c LEFT JOIN account a ON c.fid=a.id WHERE c.tid='". (int) $user[id]."' AND c.parent IS NULL ORDER BY `cid` DESC LIMIT 0, 10";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    $comments = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $cid = $row['cid'];

        // Get how many replies the comment has
        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT count(*) AS `total` FROM `user_wall` WHERE parent='".$cid."'");
        $tmp = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
        $row['rcount'] = $tmp['total'];
        $comments[] = $row;

    }
        $smarty->assign('comments', $comments);
}



{foreach item="comment" from="$comments"}
    <div class="bubble2">
        <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="cinfo">By <a href="#">{$comment.username}</a>, {$comment.time}</div>
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            {$comment.comment}
        <div class="c-actions">
            <a href="#"><i class="icon-comments"></i> ({$comment.rcount}) Replies</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
{/foreach}
```